# Does a Boot Camped Windows alongside a Mac OS X partition profit from a Fusion drive like Mac OS X does?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, performance, fusion-drive

While writing an answer to this question [Should I defrag my SSD before creating a partition for Boot Camp?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153208/should-i-defrag-my-ssd-before-creating-a-partition-for-boot-camp) i wondered if a Boot Camped Windows profits from a Fusion drive like OS X on the same drive in the sense of faster read/write access does.

The condition are clear for a pure SSD as well as for a common spinning HD.
In the first case a Windows installation profits like Mac OS X, in the second case the performance is slightly degraded because the Windows partition is almost always situated at the innermost "slower" parts of the disk.

But what's the case with a Fusion drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fusion Drive is an OS X specific way of caching data.

If you use Bootcamp on a Fusion Drive you will get Windows on the hard drive only. Some information  from this [Apple note](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5446?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Answer (score -1):

"Fusion drive" is yet another name dubbed by apple.. It's what's called generally a "hybrid ssd".

What that means is that part of the "drive" as such is "solid state", in that it world like ram/rom, and the other part is typical motorised magnetic disk hard-drive.

The boost in speed is where the "solid state" comes in. The most commonly things accessed by the system (loads of things that you won't be aware of) would be kept on there for "quick access". The things which the system wouldn't need all too often would remain on the spinning magnetic disc (which is slower to access).

All in all, it's a mid-step between spinning magnetic discs and SSD.

Personally, and as a mac user... I'd advise against spending that sort of money on a "fusion drive" and rather go for the "ssd" option.

Comment: The fusion drive differs from drive manufacturers hybrid ssd  as the fusion drive has knowledge of the directory structure not just blocks so will give better performance (i.e. it will move a whole file into SSD not just the block that is accessed)

Comment: A hybrid SSD would cache under Windows as well as OS X